# How to populate Non Linear Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

How to populate tree with the following structure
[image]

With data "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J" so after population it's structure look like that

[image]

I could easily do it with use of recursion and functions, but I was told that I can not use functions, only loops.

Here is struct I'm using

```
struct Tree
{
    int value;
    Tree* left;
    Tree* right;
};
```

Comment: Do you have the class files for the tree? It's hard to tell you how to proceed when you don't give us all the information

Comment: I use simple struct(c++). Added to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about building a complete binary tree. We can use an array to store nodes and the key is to find parent node.

```
struct Tree
{
    int val;
    Tree *left, *right;
    Tree():val(0), left(NULL), right(NULL){}
};

Tree* buildCompleteBinaryTree(const vector<int>& values)
{
    size_t len = values.size();
    if(len <= 0) return NULL;

    Tree* trees = new Tree[len];
    trees[0].val = values[0];
    for(size_t i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        trees[i].val = values[i];
        size_t par = (i - 1) / 2;
        (i % 2)?(trees[par].left = &(trees[i])):(trees[par].right = &(trees[i]));
    }

    return trees;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a queue.

For each element in the input:

- Add it to the queue.
- Then add it to the last node, either as a left child, or as a right child if it already has a left child.
- If both of the children of the last node has now been populated, make the last node the dequeued item from the queue.

In pseudo-code:

```
list = A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J

last = list.removeFront()

while !list.empty
  node = list.removeFront()
  queue.enqueue(node)
  if last.left == NULL
    last.left = node
  else
    last.right = node
    last = queue.dequeue()
```